# Dynamic Sweave document

Tags: r, latex, sweave

Is it possible to generate a LaTeX document through Sweave that don't have the number of its elements predefined? I mean, suppose I need to build a table for each row in a dataframe. The number of tables in the document will depend on the number of rows in the dataframe.

In other words, generate LaTeX elements inside a `for` loop. For each row Sweave would build a table.

The same would apply for pages, or other elements. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: A nice tutorial using `brew` is described in [this blog](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/09/09/brew-creating-repetitive-reports/)

Comment: Yes, I believe the best way to do it, in my case, is using brew to generate the tex files. This way I can use for's, if's and other control structures to generate the tex file dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{Sweave}

\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE>>=
library( xtable )
df <- structure(list(ID = 2:6, home_pc = structure(c(2L, 6L, 1L, 3L,
5L), .Label = c("BY5 8IB", "CB4 2DT", "DH4 6PB", "KN4 5GH", "MP9 7GH",
"NE5 7TH", "VB2 4RF"), class = "factor"), start_pc = structure(c(4L,
3L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("BV6 5PB", "CB3 5TH", "FC5 7YH",
"Home", "NA"), class = "factor"), end_pc = structure(c(1L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("CB5 4FG", "GH6 8HG", "Home", "NA"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID",
"home_pc", "start_pc", "end_pc"), row.names = 2:6, class = "data.frame")
count = 1
end = 3
@

<<fun,echo=FALSE,eval=FALSE>>=
print( xtable( df ) )
@


<<echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
for( i in 1:end )
{
    print( xtable( df ) )
    i <- i + 1
}
cat( "\\newpage" )
@

<<echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
if( count < end )
<<fun>>
count = count + 1
cat( "\\newpage" )
@

<<echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
if( count < end )
<<fun>>
count = count + 1
cat( "\\newpage" )
@

<<echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
if( count < end )
<<fun>>
count = count + 1
cat( "\\newpage" )
@

\end{document}
```

Happy to go into more details if this is the right track!

Comment: Edited version, using mtcars as @Ramnath does (much better than my handmade stuff) is [here](ftp://godesberg.homelinux.net/test.Rnw). I have tried do demonstrate the flexibility that comes with the admittedly longer way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter way to do the same. I am using the `mtcars` dataset in `R` and will illustrate how to create tables by number of cylinders. You can process this document using `Sweave` or `knitr` (which is the new kid on the block). Let me know how it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\SweaveOpts{echo = F}

\begin{document}
<<load-libraries>>=
suppressMessages(require(plyr))
suppressMessages(require(xtable))
@

<<gen-tables, results = tex>>=
d_ply(mtcars, .(cyl), xtable, .print = TRUE)
@

\end{document}
```